How can I detect in which Blazor page my LayoutComponentBase is currently rendered?
I have Blazor pages that are structured like so:
Index.razor:
@page "/"
@layout PageTopComponents

<div>
    <!-- html stuff here -->
</div>

@code {
    // ...
}

Results.razor:
@page "/results"
@layout PageTopComponents

<div>
    <!-- html stuff here -->
</div>

@code {
    // ...
}

PageTopComponents.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div><Component1 /></div>
<div><Component2 /></div>
<div><Component3 /></div>
<div><Component4 /></div>
<div><Component5 /></div>

In, say, Component3, I need to know whether or not I am in "/" or "/results" so I can display different information that is page specific.
I have a service with a bool that I can call to set or unset the boolean depending on which page I am on.
MyService.cs:
public bool showData_A { get; set; } = false;
public bool showData_B { get; set; } = false;
public bool showData_C { get; set; } = false;
public bool showData_D { get; set; } = false;

And I can successfully set it like so:
[Inject]
MyService myService { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    myService.showData_B = true;
}

However, I believe the PageTopComponents are getting loaded before the OnInitializedAsync is being called.
So, How can I get this to work?

you can use sections.Sections can be used in both layouts and across nested parent-child components.the  official tutorials:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0.

@XieMan Unfortunately, we are using .NET 6, and Sections is not available.

Not sure if it works, but you can try to add <CascadingValue> to layout page and see whether it is propagated to underlying components. That would be cleanest solution

you can create a service  class to do this.then addScoped in the Program.cs.I write an example use .net 6  for you .I hope this can help you.
1).LayoutService.cs
public class LayoutService
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public event Action OnChange;

    public void SetTitle(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}

2).program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<LayoutService>(); 

3).MainLayout.razor:
<article class="content px-4">
    <div><Component1 /></div>
    <Component2>
        <ChildContent>
            <h1>@LayoutService.Title</h1>
        </ChildContent>
    </Component2>
    <div><Component3 /></div>
    @Body
</article>
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        LayoutService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
    
}

4).index.razor:
@page "/Index"
@inject LayoutService LayoutService
@inject MainLayout Layout
<div>
   -- html stuff here --
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.SetTitle("Index");
    }
    
}

5).Results.razor:
@inject LayoutService LayoutService
@page "/results"

<h3>Results</h3>

@code {  
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.SetTitle("Results");
    }

}

6). The results are :


